# Why doesn't my JavaScript statement change the background image properly?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to set a background Image of a div with this code .But it is not working. If i use backgroundColor instead then it works fine .
Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this .
Sorry for noob question.

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('ab').style.backgroundImage='url("pexel.jpg")'">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Mismatched quotes are causing your issues.  Just call a function and do your work in there instead of inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error, see below

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('ab').style.backgroundImage='url(pexel.jpg)'">Click me</button>
```

Use `'url(pexel.jpg)'` instead of `'url("pexel.jpg")'`

Answer (score 0):

The quotes in the url() assignment are what's causing the issue.
You need to escape them correctly.

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('ab').style.backgroundImage='url(\'pexel.jpg\')';">Click me</button>
```